# Slow Ember Computed Property

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I've build a computed property inside my model to run a calculation on distance to a location using user location and point of interest location (in this case vineyards). The calculation seems to take a second and the template renders even when the milesAway attribute has not been set. Thus not rendering the pertinent information. Any ideas? Model code below...

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import attr from 'ember-data/attr';
import { belongsTo, hasMany } from 'ember-data/relationships';
import EmberObject, { computed, observer } from '@ember/object';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  featuredImages: hasMany('contentful-asset'),
  featured: attr('boolean'),
  name: attr('string'),
  slug: attr('string'),
  rating: attr('number'),
  location: attr('string'),
  latitude: attr('string'),
  longitude: attr('string'),
  bodyOne: attr('string'),
  milesAway: attr('string', {async: false}),
  googleMapsApi: Ember.inject.service(),
  googleLocation: computed(function() {
    let userLocation = 'Hard Coded Test Address';
    let endLocation = this.get('location');
    let milesAway = '';
    let googleMapsApi = this.get('googleMapsApi');
    this.get('googleMapsApi.google').then((google) => {
      var self = this;
      let distanceMatrixService = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
      function calculateDistance() {
        distanceMatrixService.getDistanceMatrix({
          origins: [userLocation],
          destinations: [endLocation],
          travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
          unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
          avoidHighways: false,
          avoidTolls: false
        }, callback);
      }
      function callback(response, status) {
        if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
          self.toggleProperty('errorState');
        } else {
          if (response.rows[0].elements[0].status === "ZERO_RESULTS") {
            self.toggleProperty('errorState');
          } else {
            var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance;
            var distance_text = distance.text;
            self.set('milesAway', distance_text);
          }
        }
      }
      calculateDistance();
    });
  })
});
```

Answer (score 2):

A few things stand out...

Your computed property `googleLocation` is missing it's dependencies, which will prevent it being updated. At the very least, `location` should be listed.

Also, computed properties are meant to be 'pure functions', so that they have no side-effects whenever they are executed. So, instead of setting `milesAway` within the computed function, you should return a value from your computed function, which may as well be named `milesAway`. I can't comment too much on the distance calculation part as I've not done that yet myself.

You should remove this line from your code:

```
milesAway: attr('string', {async: false}),
```

and do something like the following structure:

```
milesAway: computed('location', function() {
    let location = this.get('location');

    // Your code to calculate the distance

    return distance;  
})
```

However, models are essentially intended for persistent data rather than transient application data. milesAway will vary per user (I see you have a hardcoded userLocation while you're working on this) for each vineyard that uses this model. So, you probably want to move this computed property out of your model and into your component or controller. So, in your component or controller, you'd have:

```
milesAway: computed('model.location', function() {
    let location = this.get('model.location');

    // Your code to calculate the distance

    return distance;  
})
```

Comment: This makes sense. Could you give me some guidance as to how to put this in a component/controller and update all model attributes?

Comment: @ChrisJohnson I've created an Ember Twiddle that illustrates how this might be done for a `vineyard` route: https://ember-twiddle.com/dc740e899a80c7bbf87f5e0de8270177?openFiles=templates.vineyard.hbs%2C&route=%2Fvineyard. Note: Ember Twiddle doesn't support some of the Ember 3 syntax for importing, so the code is a little outdated, but it shows the overall structure.

Comment: Thank you casfred, this looks great. How would I set this this if each vineyard has a different value?

Comment: @ChrisJohnson In a real-word situation, your vineyard route would be passed an `vineyard_id` parameter, which it would then use to fetch the vineyard from the store and set as the model. I've added some further comments into the twiddle that show what you would do in your situation. Also, if you haven't done it recently, the Ember Tutorial 'Super Rentals' (https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.1.0/tutorial/ember-cli/) covers some of what you're trying to do and would probably save you some pain trying to work things out for yourself.

Comment: Thank you. To be clear, I mean't set if each vineyard has different values in the index route (/vineyards) showed as a list view. I will check out Super Rentals right now, thanks!

Comment: @ChrisJohnson To achieve the list view, you'd most likely use a component to display each model instance and do the computed function. I've tweaked the Twiddle to illustrate what that would look like. One last thought, Super Rentals illustrates how a service can incorporate caching, which is something you might want to consider for how you use the GoogleAPI and calculation (after you have the basic version working :-) ).

Comment: @ChrisJohnson Is there anything else regarding this question that you need help with or has it been answered?